# jQuery replace all single character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace all characters in the textarea by a click using jQuery.

For example:

ə = e, ı = i, ...

*Thıs ıs əxamplə*

By clicking it should be:

*This is example*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding on from Zikes

```
var replace_map={
    "ı":"i",
    "ə":"e"
};

$('textarea').click(function(){
    var ret='';
    $.each(this.value.split(''), function(i, str) {
        ret += replace_map[str] || str;
    })
    this.value = ret;
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wD38h/2/)**

---

**UPDATED EDIT**

```
var replace_map={
    "ı":"i",
    "ə":"e"
};

$('textarea').click(function(){
     this.value = $.map(this.value.split(''), function(str) {
        return replace_map[str] || str;
    }).join('');
});
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wD38h/5/)**

Answer (score 3):

```
$('textarea').html($('textarea').html().replace(/ə/g,'e'))
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML:

```
<textarea>Thıs ıs əxamplə</textarea>
```

JS:

```
var replace_map={
    "ı":"i",
    "ə":"e"
};

$('textarea').click(function(){
    this.value = this.value.replace(/./g,function(str){
        return replace_map[str] || str;
    })
});
```

Comment: I would +1 if this would just iterate over the string character by character and not use regex. Everyone seems to be too quick to use regex these days.

Comment: @Brad Christie it may not be as quick as character by character iteration, but unless the textarea value is tens of kilobytes in size I don't imagine the performance difference would be that extreme in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really need jQuery for that other than perhaps to select the textarea element (and then only for a microscopic amount of ease).

Past that you should be able to use just string.replace on the textarea content:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace